# Compare two arrays of object with same values and chenge/add a property of one array to the other one in Vue.js2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I have an array of objects taken from an API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction this one) that is linked to a variable that is the `v-model` of an `input`. So anytime the variable changes the array changes too with a function that calls the API when `@keyup`.
It has a structure like this:

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: we]
0:
backdrop_path: "/pLG4ihU1d2XkQbASQDjsFu9U7d9.jpg"
first_air_date: "2021-03-24"
genre_ids: Array(3)
0: 18
1: 80
2: 9648
length: 3
__ob__: we {value: Array(3), dep: ce, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
id: 120168
media_type: "tv"
name: "Che fine ha fatto Sara?"
origin_country: Array(1)
original_language: "es"
original_name: "¿Quién mató a Sara?"
overview: "Determinato a vendicarsi e a provare di essere stato incastrato per l'omicidio della sorella, Álex cerca di scoprire molto più del vero colpevole del crimine."
popularity: 529.698
poster_path: "/jnit57q25N5VvVrK4pj4Uj8BLe7.jpg"
vote_average: 7.8
vote_count: 430
```

This array provides me useful information about movies and tv-series, but it doesn't give me back the genres, not the names of these at least, but ids related to them yes.
Now, I've called another API that provides a genre list like this:

```
(19) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
id: 28
name: "Azione"
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 12
name: "Avventura"
__proto__: Object
2: {id: 16, name: "Animazione"}
3: {id: 35, name: "Commedia"}
4: {id: 80, name: "Crime"}
5: {id: 99, name: "Documentario"}
6: {id: 18, name: "Dramma"}
7: {id: 10751, name: "Famiglia"}
8: {id: 14, name: "Fantasy"}
9: {id: 36, name: "Storia"}
10: {id: 27, name: "Horror"}
11: {id: 10402, name: "Musica"}
12: {id: 9648, name: "Mistero"}
13: {id: 10749, name: "Romance"}
14: {id: 878, name: "Fantascienza"}
15: {id: 10770, name: "televisione film"}
16: {id: 53, name: "Thriller"}
17: {id: 10752, name: "Guerra"}
18: {id: 37, name: "Western"}
length: 19
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Inside of this array every object has the same genres' ids of the previous array inside the `genre-ids` sub-array. So in my logic if the genre ID inside of this sub-array is equal to one of this ids in this genres list array, it takes the name of the genre too. I'm working with Vue 2.
How can I compare both arrays, check if the first array's genres' ID match the ids included in the second array and then add to the object of the first array the names of the genres so I can print them in HTML?

Comment: I suggest you use an `array1.map` such that you can access each individual element(object) in the first array and with a loop compare it with objects in the second array, if at any point they match, you grab the object from the second array, include it in the object of the first array

Comment: Thanks I'll try! I didn't know you could match the single element, but it's an array after all

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible and short solution to give you an idea:

```js
const movies = [{genre_ids: [1,2]}, {genre_ids: [2]}, {genre_ids: [1,3]}];
const genres = [{id: 1, name: "genre1"}, {id: 2, name: "genre2"}, {id: 3, name: "genre3"}];
const moviesWithGenres = movies.map(movie => ({
    ...movie,
    genres: genres.filter(({ id }) => movie.genre_ids.includes(id))
  }));
```